# SharePoint Server Search Error: Internal server error exception

Tags: 2010, search

When performing a SharePoint Search operation on a SharePoint 2010 environment, the following error appears:

> Error: Internal Server Error Exception

**Farm topology:**

- APP01 - Application Server
- WFE01 - Web Front End Server 1
- WFE02 - Web Front End Server 2

**ULS logs**

> 03/21/2016 09:58:27.69    w3wp.exe (0x1B50)   0x2120  SharePoint Server
>   Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the
>   config is in wrong format. Input string was not in a correct
>   format.   0de31de7-6849-402c-bef3-46c375d36ed9

**Troubleshooting**

Reviewing the Search Topology it became clear the SharePoint environment was missing the Query Component. There was not a single SharePoint Query Component in the Search Topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

To solve this issue I :

- created a new Query Component on the Application Server APP01;
- performed an index reset to rebuild the index;
- executed a full crawl.

After this the search is again functional.